# Retrieving Formulas within Excel concatenate function

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013, parsing

I want to parse an excel concatenate statement to find the result of the enclosed expression. Eg: `=CONCAT("=1-2-3+7*8")` should return 52, and
`=CONCAT("=AVERAGE(A1,A2)")` should return the average of the two fields.
Is there any function or any other way to accomplish this in excel?

Comment: Why do you need **CONCAT** function to return value? You can type **=1-2-3+7*8** and **=AVERAGE(A1,A2)** directly.

Comment: The data I have is in that form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following User Defined Function:

```
Public Function raghav(rng As Range) As Variant
    Dim s As String

    s = Mid(rng(1).Formula, 2)
    arr = Split(s, Chr(34))
    For Each a In arr
        If Left(a, 1) = "=" Then
            raghav = Evaluate(a)
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next a
End Function
```

[image]

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to **install** and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To **remove** the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To **use** the UDF from Excel:

```
=raghav(A1)
```

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**